# Simple Hello World program for OpenWRT

Tags: c++, linux, embedded, openwrt

I am trying to learn OpenWRT. 
I have downloaded the sdk.
Created a simple `helloworld.cpp` file inside the `packages\helloworld` folder
created the following Makefile inside the `packages\helloworld`

**Makefile**

```
include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk
PKG_NAME:=helloworld
PKG_RELEASE:=1

PKG_BUILD_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_NAME)


include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk

define Package/helloworld
    SECTION:=utils
    CATEGORY:=Utilities
    TITLE:=Helloworld -- prints a snarky message
    Package/PKG_NAME/description:=\
    If you can't figure out what this program does, \\\
    you're probably brain-dead and need immediate \\\
    medical attention.
endef

define Build/Prepare
    mkdir -p $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
    $(CP) ./src/* $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/
endef

define Package/helloworld/install
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/bin
    $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/helloworld $(1)/bin/
endef

$(eval $(call BuildPackage,helloworld))
```

**After that I ran make command from the sdk root**

I am getting the following error

```
> naro_uClibc-0.9.33.2$ make V=s make[1]: Entering directory
> '/home/sukesh/Desktop/SDK/OpenWrt-SDK-x86-for-linux-i486-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2'
> make[2]: Entering directory
> '/home/sukesh/Desktop/SDK/OpenWrt-SDK-x86-for-linux-i486-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2'
> make[3]: Entering directory
> '/home/sukesh/Desktop/SDK/OpenWrt-SDK-x86-for-linux-i486-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/package/helloworld' CFLAGS="-O2 -pipe -march=i486 -fno-caller-saves -fhonour-copts
> -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable  -I/home/sukesh/Desktop/SDK/OpenWrt-SDK-x86-for-linux-i486-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/staging_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/include
> -I/home/sukesh/Desktop/SDK/OpenWrt-SDK-x86-for-linux-i486-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/staging_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.33.2/include
> -I/home/sukesh/Desktop/SDK/OpenWrt-SDK-x86-for-linux-i486-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/staging_dir/toolchain-i386_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/include
> -I/home/sukesh/Desktop/SDK/OpenWrt-SDK-x86-for-linux-i486-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/staging_dir/toolchain-i386_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/include " CXXFLAGS="-O2 -pipe -march=i486 -fno-caller-saves -fhonour-copts
> -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable  -I/home/sukesh/Desktop/SDK/OpenWrt-SDK-x86-for-linux-i486-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/staging_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/include
> -I/home/sukesh/Desktop/SDK/OpenWrt-SDK-x86-for-linux-i486-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/staging_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.33.2/include
> -I/home/sukesh/Desktop/SDK/OpenWrt-SDK-x86-for-linux-i486-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/staging_dir/toolchain-i386_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/include
> -I/home/sukesh/Desktop/SDK/OpenWrt-SDK-x86-for-linux-i486-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/staging_dir/toolchain-i386_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/include "
> LDFLAGS="-L/home/sukesh/Desktop/SDK/OpenWrt-SDK-x86-for-linux-i486-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/staging_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/lib
> -L/home/sukesh/Desktop/SDK/OpenWrt-SDK-x86-for-linux-i486-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/staging_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.33.2/lib -L/home/sukesh/Desktop/SDK/OpenWrt-SDK-x86-for-linux-i486-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/staging_dir/toolchain-i386_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/lib -L/home/sukesh/Desktop/SDK/OpenWrt-SDK-x86-for-linux-i486-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/staging_dir/toolchain-i386_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/lib " make -j1 -C
> /home/sukesh/Desktop/SDK/OpenWrt-SDK-x86-for-linux-i486-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/build_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.33.2/helloworld/.
> AR=i486-openwrt-linux-uclibc-ar AS="ccache_cc -c -O2 -pipe -march=i486
> -fno-caller-saves -fhonour-copts -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable" LD=i486-openwrt-linux-uclibc-ld NM=i486-openwrt-linux-uclibc-nm
> CC="ccache_cc" GCC="ccache_cc" CXX="ccache_cxx"
> RANLIB=i486-openwrt-linux-uclibc-ranlib
> STRIP=i486-openwrt-linux-uclibc-strip
> OBJCOPY=i486-openwrt-linux-uclibc-objcopy
> OBJDUMP=i486-openwrt-linux-uclibc-objdump
> SIZE=i486-openwrt-linux-uclibc-size CROSS="i486-openwrt-linux-uclibc-"
> ARCH="i386" ; make[4]: Entering directory
> '/home/sukesh/Desktop/SDK/OpenWrt-SDK-x86-for-linux-i486-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/build_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.33.2/helloworld'
> make[4]: *** Notargets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
> make[4]: Leaving directory
> '/home/sukesh/Desktop/SDK/OpenWrt-SDK-x86-for-linux-i486-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/build_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.33.2/helloworld'
> Makefile:32: recipe for target
> '/home/sukesh/Desktop/SDK/OpenWrt-SDK-x86-for-linux-i486-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/build_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.33.2/helloworld/.built'
> failed make[3]: ***
> [/home/sukesh/Desktop/SDK/OpenWrt-SDK-x86-for-linux-i486-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/build_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.33.2/helloworld/.built]
> Error 2 make[3]: Leaving directory
> '/home/sukesh/Desktop/SDK/OpenWrt-SDK-x86-for-linux-i486-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/package/helloworld' package/Makefile:105: recipe for target 'package/helloworld/compile'
> failed make[2]: *** [package/helloworld/compile] Error 2 make[2]:
> Leaving directory
> '/home/sukesh/Desktop/SDK/OpenWrt-SDK-x86-for-linux-i486-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2'
> package/Makefile:101: recipe for target
> '/home/sukesh/Desktop/SDK/OpenWrt-SDK-x86-for-linux-i486-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/staging_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.33.2/stamp/.package_compile' failed make[1]: ***
> [/home/sukesh/Desktop/SDK/OpenWrt-SDK-x86-for-linux-i486-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/staging_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.33.2/stamp/.package_compile] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory
> '/home/sukesh/Desktop/SDK/OpenWrt-SDK-x86-for-linux-i486-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2'
> /home/sukesh/Desktop/SDK/OpenWrt-SDK-x86-for-linux-i486-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/include/toplevel.mk:144:
> recipe for target 'world' failed make: *** [world] Error 2
```

**Can anyone please help me to find out what is the error?**

Comment: @LethalProgrammer, You are a life saver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also added own package in openwrt, and this is my Makefile refer this. I hope this will helps.

```
include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk

PKG_NAME:=viva
PKG_VERSION:=1.4
PKG_RELEASE=$(PKG_SOURCE_VERSION)
PKG_MAINTAINER:=Vishal <yourname@domain.for.your.name>
PKG_LICENSE:=ISC

include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk

define Package/viva/default
  CATEGORY:=Network
  SUBMENU:=Web Servers/Proxies
  TITLE:=Webpage for package creation
endef

define Package/viva
  $(Package/viva/default)
  DEPENDS:=+uhttpd
endef

define Package/viva/description
    A web page used for illustrating package creation
endef

define Package/viva/install
    $(CP) ./files/* $(1)/
endef

define Build/Compile
    true
endef

$(eval $(call BuildPackage,viva))
```